# how to plot scatterplot and histogram using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset about maximum wind speed(cm) as below:

```
Year Jan Feb Mar Apr May June July Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec     
2011 4.5 5.6 5.0 5.4 5.0 5.0  5.2  5.3 4.8  5.4 5.4 3.8     
2010 4.6 5.0 5.8 5.0 5.2 4.5  4.4  4.3 4.9  5.2 5.2 4.6     
2009 4.5 5.3 4.3 3.9 4.7 5.0  4.8  4.7 4.9  5.6 4.9 4.1     
2008 3.8 1.9 5.6 4.7 4.7 4.3  5.9  4.9 4.9  5.6 5.2 4.4     
2007 4.6 4.6 4.6 5.6 4.2 3.6  2.5  2.5 2.5  3.3 5.6 1.5     
2006 4.3 4.8 5.0 5.2 4.7 4.6  3.2  3.4 3.6  3.9 5.9 4.4     
2005 2.7 4.3 5.7 4.7 4.6 5.0  5.6  5.0 4.9  5.9 5.6 1.8
```

How to create monthly max wind speed scatterplot (month in x-axis and wind speed in y-axis) and also the monthly max wind speed histogram by using R programming?

Comment: plot(), hist() or http://ggplot2.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading an introduction to R, but this should get you started.

```
df <- read.table(text="Year Jan Feb Mar Apr May June July Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec     
2011 4.5 5.6 5.0 5.4 5.0 5.0  5.2  5.3 4.8  5.4 5.4 3.8     
2010 4.6 5.0 5.8 5.0 5.2 4.5  4.4  4.3 4.9  5.2 5.2 4.6     
2009 4.5 5.3 4.3 3.9 4.7 5.0  4.8  4.7 4.9  5.6 4.9 4.1     
2008 3.8 1.9 5.6 4.7 4.7 4.3  5.9  4.9 4.9  5.6 5.2 4.4     
2007 4.6 4.6 4.6 5.6 4.2 3.6  2.5  2.5 2.5  3.3 5.6 1.5     
2006 4.3 4.8 5.0 5.2 4.7 4.6  3.2  3.4 3.6  3.9 5.9 4.4     
2005 2.7 4.3 5.7 4.7 4.6 5.0  5.6  5.0 4.9  5.9 5.6 1.8",header=TRUE)
#look at ?read.csv to learn how to read your data from a CSV file

#transform data.frame into long format
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df,id="Year",variable.name = "Month",value.name = "Speed")

#plot boxplots per month
plot(Speed~Month,data=df)
```

[image: boxplot]

```
#histogram for January
hist(df$Speed[df$Month=="Jan"],main="Max wind speed in January",xlab="Speed")
```

[image: histogram Jan]

```
#histogram for 2011
hist(df$Speed[df$Year==2011],main="Max wind speed in 2011",xlab="Speed")
```

[image: histogram 2011]

```
#create actual dates
df$Month2 <- factor(df$Month)
levels(df$Month2) <- 1:12
df <- transform(df,Time = as.Date(paste(Year,Month2,"15",sep="-"),'%Y-%m-%d'))
#plot Speed vs Time
plot(Speed~Time,data=df[order(df$Time),],type="l")
```

[image: time series]

Comment: thx for your reply. Im able to plot a scatterplot of yearly maximum, which is the maximum of each year. for maximum of each month in each yr,can the output of plot(Speed~Month,data=df) in scatterplot instead of boxplot?

Comment: `df$Month2 <- as.numeric(df$Month2); plot(Speed~Month2,data=df)`

Comment: very thank you for your help and reply. u help me alot. thank you once again! =)